# Problem accessing LinkedIn from an iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api

I receive the following message after login in to linkedin in my Iphone App.It cant access the contacts or any other information from linked in.Just give the following message.[image]

Successfully Authorized (App name)
Application and enter the following security code to grant access.

(I dnt see any security code)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [sample LinkedIn client](https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client)

It shows you exactly how to setup authorising an account using OAuth.